# How can I catch an error in this program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to catch an error in the following code:

```
n=int(input("enter the first number: "))
m=int(input("enter the second number: "))
p=n/m
try :
    print( n/m)
except :
    print("dividing by zero may not be possible")
print(p)
```

and here is the output

```
enter the first number: 5
enter the second number: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py113.py", line 4, in <module>
    p=n/m
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Please point out my mistake.

Comment: You divide by zero *outside* the try block. Why not just check `if m == 0:`?

Comment: Additional: Don't use a bare `except` if you want to catch a well defined error. In this case it should be `except ZeroDivisionError:`.

Comment: You *do* catch the error *once*, but you make the error *twice*.

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `m` is equal to 0 before dividing or inserting the `p=n/m` into your try clause. Additionally, you don't want to use bare `except` but something like `except ZeroDivisionError:` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input("enter the first number: "))
m = int(input("enter the second number: "))

try:
    p = n / m
    print(n / m)
    print(p)    
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("dividing by zero may not be possible")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating p outside of the try/except block. Simply add p=n/m inside the try block, so if that throws an exception it will be handled by the except block. Think of the try block as a box, whatever explodes inside the box can be handled, if it explodes outside the box it cannot be handled.

Also, it is recommended that you specify which type of exception you are trying to catch as many exceptions can occur such as 'dividing by zero', 'dividing by a non number', etc... it might not seem necessary but when you have a lot code it helps a lot with debugging -- otherwise you'd never know why your program failed.

```
n = int(input("enter the first number: "))
m = int(input("enter the second number: "))

try:
    p = n/m
    print(p)    
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("dividing by zero may not be possible")
```

Comment: that was of great help,thnx